# DJango testing multiple database application

Tags: python, django

I have django application which has two database `defaultdb` and `externdb`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        "NAME": config("DB_NAME"),
        "USER": config("DB_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": config("DB_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": config("DB_HOST"),
        "PORT": config("DB_PORT"),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        },
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test_{0}'.format(config("DB_NAME")),
            'MIRROR': "default",
        },
    },
    'extern': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': config("DB_EXTERN_NAME"),
        'USER': config("DB_EXTERN_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': config("DB_EXTERN_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': config("DB_EXTERN_HOST"),
        'PORT': config("DB_EXTERN_PORT"),
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test_{0}'.format(config("DB_EXTERN_NAME")),
            'MIRROR': "extern",
        },
    }
}
```

The application works well but when testing ,this error occurs below

when trying to access the extern database

```
from extern_db.models import TBasicInfo

class HelpViewTest(TestCase):
    def test_api(self):
        tb = TBasicInfo.objects.get(info_id=10352)
```

This error occurs

```
AssertionError: Database queries to 'extern' are not allowed in this test. Add 'extern' to defapp.tests.HelpViewTest.databases to ensure proper test isolation and silence this failure.
```

which setting should I check??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
    tb = TBasicInfo.objects.get(info_id=10352)
```

to this:

```
    tb = TBasicInfo.objects.using("extern").get(info_id=10352)
```

---

**OR**

You can also add databases = "extern" to this:

```
from extern_db.models import TBasicInfo

class HelpViewTest(TestCase):
    def test_api(self):
        tb = TBasicInfo.objects.get(info_id=10352)
```

final version:

```
from extern_db.models import TBasicInfo

class HelpViewTest(TestCase):
    databases = 'extern'

    def test_api(self):
        tb = TBasicInfo.objects.get(info_id=10352)
```

This method is what it basically suggests you to do in that message.

Comment: The finalway  `databases = 'extern'` works well for me. thank you very much.